# Some Architecture advise for Reacjs with Apollo and Graphql (serius project)?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

With our team, we are going to start a medium project with Reactjs + Apollo + Graphql and we are looking architecture pattern to keep an order on this project.

I was reading and watching some videos about Architecture for Reactjs and the most commented was Redux, seem good it have state managment and a file structure for work (like layers) but work better with Api Rest and we want to use Graphql.

The other option is use only Graphql and Apollo, because Apollo have it's own state managment and similar options that can replace redux, but if we use this option, what architecture can we give it? mvp? or mvvm? Is it posible with Reactjs?.

If some one with experencie with Reactjs can advise us, we would appreciate it =)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should first understands the benefit of using ReactJs within your project. By saying this I mean to say that React and Redux are independent of each other. These are two different libraries.

React offers it's own benefits such as virtual DOM manipulation, lightweight, used with styled components and many more.

On the other hand Redux is kind of state management library that is based on centralized state management pattern and can be integrated with any JS framework.

With React you get the flavor of creating SPA's or even you can provide the illusion of SPA having multiple pages inside your App.

With React you can use other JS libraries without any obstacles as it is very user friendly and compatible with almost all latest browsers and even to aid the support there are various other libraries too.